# how to adjust/resize entry grid column width by mouse ( like as treeview tkinter python)

Tags: tkinter

how to adjust or resize the width of the columns in an entry grid using the mouse, similar to the functionality in the treeview module of tkinter. The entry grid consists of 8 columns, and it allows users to resize the column width according to their requirements by simply using the mouse.
(tkinter python)

i am new in tkinter

Answer (score 0):

To create resizable columns in an entry grid in tkinter, you can use the *ResizableGrid* class provided below.

This class creates a grid with 8 columns where the width of each column can be adjusted using the mouse.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class ResizableGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        self.entry_grid = [[tk.Entry(self) for _ in range(columns)] for _ in range(rows)]
        self.configure_grid()

        self.bind_mouse()

    def configure_grid(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.columns):
                self.entry_grid[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                self.entry_grid[i][j].bind("<Enter>", lambda event, col=j: self.on_enter(event, col))

        for i in range(self.rows):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        for j in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)

    def bind_mouse(self):
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_motion)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

    def on_enter(self, event, col):
        self.current_column = col

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if hasattr(self, "current_column"):
            col = self.current_column
            width = event.x - self.entry_grid[0][col].winfo_x()
            self.columnconfigure(col, minsize=max(50, width))

    def on_release(self, event):
        if hasattr(self, "current_column"):
            delattr(self, "current_column")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Resizable Grid")

    rows = 5
    columns = 8

    grid = ResizableGrid(root, rows, columns)
    grid.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. My next requirement involves moving columns in a tkinter grid using the mouse. I would like to be able to change the location of a column or replace it with another column, similar to how it is done in Excel. For example, if I have 10 columns in the grid and the quantity is in the 4th column, I would like to be able to pick the quantity column with the mouse and drop it in the last or any other position column.     thank you for your valuable help

Comment: give it a try and tell me if not worked